# Networking pattern based on NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

I've been traditionally using a pattern where NSOperation subclasses create and manage their own NSURLConnection. The NSOperation subclass is instantiated by the view controller and will do its work without bothering the controller until it has finished. When it finishes retrieving data, it executes the completion block supplied by the view controller.

1. ViewController instantiates NSOperation subclass (which encapsulates URL, parameters etc)
2. NSOperation subclass instanciates NSURLConnection (which performs synchronous request and retrieves data)
3. NSURLConnection dumps data to NSOperation-subclass
4. NSOperation-subclass executes the completion block supplied by the view controller.

I'm trying to implement the same pattern with NSURLSession now. I want to be able to encapsulate the url and parameters required to make a network request inside a single object. Do I achieve this using NSURLSession subclasses or NSURLSessionTask subclasses?

I like to create separate classes for every network operation based on the actor design pattern.

Comment: Did you try to take a look at AFNetworking ? I see no reason to invent a wheel again :)

Comment: AFNetworking is fine for one-off requests. Here I'm basically trying to encapsulate requests into separate classes.

Comment: @GrzegorzKrukowski In AFN, if it uses an underlying `NSURLSessionTask`, the AFN class is not a subclass of `NSOperation`. Only if it uses an underlying `NSURLConnection`, the corresponding AFN class is a subclass of `NSOperation`. If you need a NSOperation subclass, you can't use AFN with `NSURLSessionTask`.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper "If you need a NSOperation subclass" its actually the opposite. I'm trying to do away with creating NSOperation subclasses. But I want all requests to be encapsulated into separate classes. I want my view controllers to instantiate the a GetSomeResourceFromNetwork with parameters and pass it a completion black.

Comment: @NSExplorer, see my updated answer. You can't subclass `NSURLSessionTask`, but you can wrap it in a thin object.

Comment: @NSExplorer You'll need something which will behave similar as NSOperation, since you need cancellation and a means to signal the call-site when a request finished. Why not NSOperation? An simple alternative for a subclass of `NSOperation` would a Promise (or Future) which represents an _eventual_ result and is also cancelable (cancels the associated asynchronous tasks). The underlying implementation will still be something *similar* to a NSOperation. You may take a look here: https://gist.github.com/couchdeveloper/7669021 and here [RXPromise](https://github.com/couchdeveloper/RXPromise)

Comment: @NSExplorer: Am also trying to implement the same. Can you let me the solution you have implemented. It would be great if you could share the code as well.

Comment: Can anyone suggest me the right way pls???

Comment: "I want to be able to encapsulate the url and parameters required to make a network request inside a single object." You mean... `NSURLRequest`? That's what it's for. Use a category to create factory methods on that for each of your specialized requests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the same pattern, replacing `NSURLConnection` with `NSURLSessionTask` subclasses (e.g. `NSURLSessionDataTask`).

As @CouchDeveloper suggests in the comments, an alternative is to wrap `NSURLSessionTask` in an non-`NSOperation` object with asynchronous semantics (cancel, resume, etc.). This wrapper object would do little more than encode and decode parameters, delegating most operations to the wrapped task.

In either case, to instantiate `NSURLSessionTask`, you will need a `NSURLSession`. (`NSURLSession` is the `NSURLSessionTask` factory.) If all of your operations use the same [configuration](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/Reference/Reference.html) (cookies, proxy, caching, etc.), you can simply use the shared session (`+[NSURLSession sharedSession]`). If they need different configurations, you'll have to give them a `NSURLSession` or enough information to create their own.

Comment: I'd like to do away with subclassing NSOperation altogether. Is there a way I could subclass NSURLSessionTask, set default parameters inside init and simply assign one per resource like GetPersonDataSessionTask, PostPersonDataSessionTask ?

Comment: For several reasons, there's no way to subclass `NSURLSessionTask` and get that working. However, you can use a _custom_ class with a similar API and behavior as `NSOperation`, but isn't a subclass of it. It should employ an asynchronous style, that is it should have a `start` method. It should also be cancelable, that is it should have a `cancel` method, and it should have a means to signal completion, either a completion handler or some kind of promise or future.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper You might not be able to easily subclass `NSURLSessionTask`, but you can easily wrap these tasks in `NSOperation` subclasses (I've done this with both block-based tasks (trivial) and delegate-based tasks (non-trivial, but not too bad)). So, I'm not following why you don't think you cannot do this, and what you gain by making your own non-NSOperation class with an API like `NSOperation`. Perhaps a different approach is useful for background sessions, but for standard sessions, an operation-based approach doesn't seem that bad.

Comment: @Rob You certainly *can* create a subclass of `NSOperation` and wrap a `NSURLSessionTask`. The OP just don't *want* to subclass from `NSOperation`. Since the API of an `NSOperation` would be quite suitable for that, I suggested the OP's custom class to have a "similar" API.

Comment: Sorry, yeah. Very good. I must confess that I blithely disregarded that part of the question. There's a natural misconception that "oh, session tasks just look like operations, so I can do away with operations in my code now." But as I'm sure you know, this is not the case, tasks are not operations, and if one was doing operations with `NSURLConnection`, you'd probably still do so with `NSURLSessionTask`, too (except for background sessions). But I guess if the OP wanted to lose the functionality operations brought to the table, I guess he could, though I'm not sure why he'd want to.

Answer (score 11):

The `NSURLSessionTask` class (and its subclasses) look a bit like operations, but they're not. Thus, you can remove operations from your code as you transition to `NSURLSession`, but if you do, you will lose certain `NSOperation` functionality (dependencies, controlling degree of concurrency, etc.). I'm not sure why you'd want to excise operations from your code as you transition to `NSURLSession`. Personally, anywhere I used to wrap a `NSURLConnection` in an operation, I now wrap a `NSURLSessionTask` with an operation.

As an aside, one of the significant annoyances with `NSURLSession`, though, is that the *task* delegates are set at the *session* object. We can make guesses why Apple did that, but it has all sorts of unfortunate implications. Clearly you can get around this by using the block based factory methods for creating your tasks, but then you lose the richness of the delegate API, if you happened to need that.

The implication of this is that if using block-based task factory methods, wrapping the task in a concurrent `NSOperation` subclass is fairly obvious. But, if using the delegate-based tasks, though, if you want custom handlers for the tasks, you have to go through some silliness with maintaining a mapping between task identifiers and the appropriate completion blocks (which I personally put in a session manager object that I used to wrap the `NSURLSession`). (FYI, I believe an implementation like this is expected in a forthcoming AFNetworking update, too. See the latter part of the discussion on [Issue 1504](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/1504) on the AFNetworking github site.)

Anyway, others have answered the question how you could replace your operation-based `NSURLConnection` code with non-operation-based `NSURLSession` code, but I'd personally suggest staying with operations.

---

By the way, I've uploaded a example implementation of an operation-based `NSURLSession` implementation on github: https://github.com/robertmryan/NetworkManager

This is not intended to be a complete solution, but illustrates the idea of how you might implement a delegate-based `NSURLSession` with `NSOperation` subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to be able to encapsulate the url and parameters required to make a network request inside a single object. Do I achieve this using NSURLSession subclasses or NSURLSessionTask subclasses?

What you are describing is `NSURLRequest`. Both `NSURLSession` and `NSURLConnection` take `NSURLRequest`s to perform network connections (the `NSURLRequest` is what it's performing). What you seem to want is a set of factory methods for generating different, specialized `NSURLRequests`. For example, one that describes the "get my mail" request.
You can do this easily by creating a category on `NSURLRequest` itself. Example:

```
@implementation NSURLRequest (Mail)

+ (instancetype) mailRequestForUser:(NSString *)user {
    NSURLRequest *result = nil;
    result = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"someServer""]];
    // set user in a header, whatever

    // return immutable copy
    return [result copy];
}

@end
```

Create something similar to the above that meets your needs. The resulting `NSURLRequest`s can then be used to create connections. In Cocoa this is a very typical pattern for customizing objects, instead of subclassing. Subclassing is pretty rare - instead Cocoa has other mechanisms for customizing class behavior, from factory methods ("convenience methods" like the above) to delegation (where an object is given responsibility for the behavior of another object).

Answer (score 0):

What I did - is just allow `Operation` and `URLSessionTask` remain separately. For doing this I made general purpose asynchronous block operation which is used to instantiate, resume, cancel `URLSessionTask`.

So, in ViewController or Data layer I'm still using chained `Operations` with `URLSessionTasks` inside. Sample code below can be extended by subclassing `AsynchronousBlockOperation`.

File 1. Generic asynchronous operation.

```
open class AsynchronousOperation: Operation {

   private var lockOfProperties = NonRecursiveLock.makeDefaultLock()

   private var mFinished = false
   private var mExecuting = false

   public override init() {
      super.init()
   }

   /// Subclasses must launch job here.
   ///
   /// **Note** called between willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey calls, but after property mExecuting is set.
   open func onStart() {
   }

   /// Subclasses must cancel job here.
   ///
   /// **Note** called immediately after calling super.cancel().
   open func onCancel() {
   }

   /// Subclasses must release job here.
   ///
   /// **Note** called between willChangeValueForKey and didChangeValueForKey calls,
   /// but after properties mExecuting and mFinished are set.
   open func onFinish() {
   }
}

extension AsynchronousOperation {

   public final override var isAsynchronous: Bool {
      return true
   }

   public final override var isExecuting: Bool {
      return lockOfProperties.synchronized { mExecuting }
   }

   public final override var isFinished: Bool {
      return lockOfProperties.synchronized { mFinished }
   }
}

extension AsynchronousOperation {

   public final override func start() {
      if isCancelled || isFinished || isExecuting {
         return
      }
      willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isExecuting))
      lockOfProperties.synchronized { mExecuting = true }
      onStart()
      didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isExecuting))
   }

   public final override func cancel() {
      super.cancel()
      if isExecuting {
         onCancel()
         finish()
      } else {
         onCancel()
         lockOfProperties.synchronized {
            mExecuting = false
            mFinished = true
         }
      }
   }

   public final func finish() {
      willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isExecuting))
      willChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isFinished))
      lockOfProperties.synchronized {
         mExecuting = false
         mFinished = true
      }
      onFinish()
      didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isExecuting))
      didChangeValue(forKey: #keyPath(Operation.isFinished))
   }
}
```

File 2. Asynchronous block based operation:

```
open class AsynchronousBlockOperation: AsynchronousOperation {

   public typealias WorkItemType = OperationCancelationType & OperationResumingType
   public typealias FinaliseBlock = () -> Void
   public typealias WorkItemBlock = (@escaping FinaliseBlock) -> WorkItemType?

   private var executionBlock: WorkItemBlock
   private var blockExecutionQueue: DispatchQueue?
   private var workItemToken: WorkItemType?

   public init(blockExecutionQueue: DispatchQueue? = nil, executionBlock: @escaping WorkItemBlock) {
      self.blockExecutionQueue = blockExecutionQueue
      self.executionBlock = executionBlock
      super.init()
   }

   open override func onStart() {
      if let queue = blockExecutionQueue {
         queue.async {
            self.execute()
         }
      } else {
         execute()
      }
   }

   open override func onCancel() {
      workItemToken?.cancelOperation()
   }

   private func execute() {
      workItemToken = executionBlock { [weak self] in
         self?.finish()
      }
      if var token = workItemToken {
         token.resumeOperation()
      } else {
         finish()
      }
   }
}
```

File 3. Protocols

```
public protocol OperationCancelationType {
   mutating func cancelOperation()
}

public protocol OperationResumingType {
   mutating func resumeOperation()
}

extension URLSessionTask: OperationCancelationType {
   public func cancelOperation() {
      cancel()
   }
}

extension URLSessionTask: OperationResumingType {
   public func resumeOperation() {
      resume()
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
let operation = AsynchronousBlockOperation { [weak self] finalise in
   return session.dataTask(with: url) {
      ...
      finalise() // This will finish operation
   }
}
```