# How can I cast my NSURLSessionDownloadTask to my custom NSURLSessionDownloadTask (inheritance)?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, casting, nsurlsession

I have created a custom **NSURLSessionDownloadTask** named **VJSessionTask** and I have just added some custom things like a *type (enum)* and a *custom object (id)*:

```
@interface VJSessionTask : NSURLSessionDownloadTask

typedef enum    types
{
    LS, LSH, DL, UL, RM, TH

}               type;

@property enum types type;

@property (strong, nonatomic) id customObject;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *progressNotif;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *doneNotif;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSURL *tmpFile;

@end
```

And when I do this:

```
VJSessionTask *taskSession = (VJSessionTask *)[self.prioritySession downloadTaskWithRequest:listFileRequest];
// init taskSession with its type
taskSession.type = LS;
```

I get this error:

```
-[__NSCFLocalDownloadTask setType:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1556198f0
```

Then I come to you as I don't understand or I don't know how to do that...
Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: A cast doesn't change the type of object that `downloadTaskWithRequest` actually instantiates. It only tells the compiler what class you believe it to be (and thus controlling what compile-time errors/warnings you may or may not receive). Thus, despite your cast, the standard `downloadTaskWithRequest` still instantiates a `NSURLSessionDownloadTask`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSURLSessionTasks are not strictly speaking subclass-able unfortunately. This is evident in that the system can queue a data task and return a NSCFLocalDownloadTask (presumably meaning that the task will return its content from the cache).

The best way to go about doing this is to borrow on from the architectural decision of [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and have individual taskDelegates that monitor all the responses an individual task works on. Then when you want to find the data relating to a task you can query your dictionary of taskDelegates. Each task has a unique identifier that you can use to key your dictionary with.

In AFNetworking you can see the taskDelegate is defined as follows:

```
@interface AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate : NSObject <NSURLSessionTaskDelegate, NSURLSessionDataDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) AFURLSessionManager *manager;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableData *mutableData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSProgress *progress;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSURL *downloadFileURL;
@property (nonatomic, copy) AFURLSessionDownloadTaskDidFinishDownloadingBlock downloadTaskDidFinishDownloading;
@property (nonatomic, copy) AFURLSessionTaskCompletionHandler completionHandler;
@end

@implementation AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate
```

and subsequently retrieved as follows:

```
- (AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate *)delegateForTask:(NSURLSessionTask *)task {
    NSParameterAssert(task);

    AFURLSessionManagerTaskDelegate *delegate = nil;
    [self.lock lock];
    delegate = self.mutableTaskDelegatesKeyedByTaskIdentifier[@(task.taskIdentifier)];
    [self.lock unlock];

    return delegate;
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21148006/networking-pattern-based-on-nsurlsession) for more info

Comment: I just got an idea, I this a good idea to use *objc_setAssociatedObject* ? And if yes, how can I keep my associated object ?

Comment: Otherwise, can I add custom properties to this *NSURLSessionDownloadTask* ?

Comment: @Kerosene you can't subclass the task to add any properties and using the objc runtime should only be a last resort for when you really know your way around the runtime

Comment: but it will definitely solve your problem whilst ignoring an overall architecture entirely:)

Comment: OK, Then, do you think that the simplest solution for me is to create a *NSMutableDictionnary* and add *my task at the task.taskIdentifier index* each time I create one ? To retrieve associated data with this task I search in my Dictionnary ?

Comment: @Kerosene its not quite clear what exactly you want to achieve but yes having a single interface to your network is definitely a good start. Then monitor task states and update your objects with the tasks

Comment: Can I by any way add *pointer to an object (id)* in the *NSURLSessionDownloadTask* ? I have a lot of different *NSURLSessionDownloadTasks* which are launched concurrently. Because of there asynchronous nature, they return in a random order. My problem is to be able to retrieve which download has returned, using the *NSURLSessionDownloadTask*. I could build a *NSMutableDictionary* of all the download tasks, but I find this particularly inelegant and cumbersome...

Comment: each task has a unique identifier that can be used to build a dictionary. Conversely you can use KVO to observe changes to a tasks state. Adding a pointer to the object is almost the same as adding a dictionary the only difference is that you are now managing the memory structure? Please look at AFNetworking, its the most popular open source networking library on iOS and most of your answers will be solved perusing their code